# Incremented iterator std::next when swapping

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, swap

Consider the code:

```
list<int> a{ 4,3,1,2 };
auto i = a.begin();
swap(*i, *(++i));
```

Why does the swap do nothing? While the following works as expected?

```
list<int> a{ 4,3,1,2 };
auto i = a.begin();
swap(*i, *(next(i)));
```

Comment: Why do you think that it does nothing?

Comment: @eerorika the evaluation order of parameters is very much compiler dependent, so they may get different results than you do.

Comment: There is a simpler way to swap: `std::iter_swap(i, std::next(i))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first code, the order of evaluation of the two ops `*i` and `*(++i)` [unspecified after c++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), hence the second one may execute before the first, and then the swapping swaps two equivalent values.

In the attached link, u can see that

> `f(++i, ++i);       // undefined behavior until C++17, unspecified after C++17`

But in the second code you have different parameters and `std::next()` returns a new iterator.